# select from two list different

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have two list list content listearticle and this the code of this list:

```
 model = (
     from article in db.Article
     select new
     {
        ID = article.ID,
        ARTICLE = article.CODEARTICLE,
        PRIX= article.PRIX,
        STOCK=article.STOCK,
        IMAGE = article.Image,
        DESCRIPTION= article.REFERENCE,
     });
```

and another content list convention and this is the code :

```
  var query = (
         from article in db.convention
         select new
         {
              ID = article.ID,
              ARTICLE = article.CODEARTICLE,
              PRIX = article.Prix,
         });
```

i want to have a list listarticleconvention like this:

foreach (dynamic aa in model)
            {

```
            foreach (dynamic aa1 in list1)
            {
                if (aa.ARTICLE == aa1.ARTICLE) 
                {
                    aa.PRIXVHT = aa1.PRIXVHT;
                }
            }
        }
```

Can someone help me to edit PRIXVHT when this article exist in list1 and thank you for your help
the error apperead is Additional information: **Property or indexer '<>f__AnonymousType3.PRIXVHT' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only**
i know that's just read  **read only**  but i need to edit it  how can i do it

**N.B**/i have to use a form like that i mean something like foreach in this two list

Answer (score 5):

You can join `db.Article` to `db.convention` and then select `article.PRIX` if  `query.PRIX` is null.

```
from articleA in db.Article
join articleC in db.convention on articleC.ID equals articleA.ID into temp
from query in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
 {
    ID = articleA.ID,
    ARTICLE = articleA.CODEARTICLE,
    PRIX = (query== null ? articleA.PRIX : query.PRIX),
    STOCK = articleA.STOCK,
    IMAGE = articleA.Image,
    DESCRIPTION = articleA.REFERENCE,
 });
```

Comment: i don't like a jointure i want foreach from this two list  for reason flexibility and rapidity because list article is so long an database

Comment: @user5994736 Have you actually tried the code Jaco posted to see if it is slower? You might be surprised.

Comment: The mix of `articleA` and `article` in the code will fail.  Can you fix please?

Comment: Thanks @Corey, have fixed it